# Using the nested element module in cvs task in ant build.xml

Tags: ant, cvs, build.xml, wincvs, cvsnt

I have problems connecting to CVS using ant build.xml.
I figured out the reason was whitespaces in package attribute of CVS task as:

```
<cvs cvsRoot=":pserver:user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/CVSREPO_CCP_MIG" dest="${basedir}" package="My Test Project"/>
```

I learned from the ant website( http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/cvs.html ) that we may Use a nested <module> element if you want to specify a module with spaces in its name. This specifies a package/module to work on, unlike the package attribute, modules specified using this attribute can contain spaces in their name.

I tried using the following:

```
<cvs cvsRoot=":pserver:user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/CVSREPO_CCP_MIG" dest="${basedir}">
<module name="My Test Project"/>
</cvs>
```

This again complains:

```
build.xml:39: cvs doesn't support the nested "module" element.
```

How can I use the module element with the CVS tag?

The Ant version is 1.7.x.

Comment: I used the CVS Official repository to test your code. It worked... I'm on ANT 1.8.2

Comment: @abksrv - `<module>` was added at Ant version 1.8.0: http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.8.0.html.  I guess you are using an older version.

Comment: @martinclayton you are right there. I'm on 1.7.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the comments above, the nested "module" element is available for Ant ver 1.8 +.
However, if you are on one of the earlier versions, you may specify your package/module name under package attribute of CVS task by adding '"' on the either end of the attribute value.
e.g. We can replace *package="My Test Project"* with *package=""My Test Project""* in here.